# Purchased new MacBook Pro on 16th October 2011; question about Up-To-Date program

Tags: macos, mac, upgrade

I purchased a new MBP and am eligible for their free Lion upgrade program; I applied for it but it would take anywhere between 5-7 business days for my country. If I purchase Lion now, will I get a refund after entering update code into iTunes?

Comment: If you purchased a Mac after July 20th, 2011 it already comes with OS X Lion. You say you purchased your new Mac on the 16th of October, 2011? It definitely should come with Lion. Where did you buy this Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confirmation of refund from apple and it seems that this is possible to do if you explain your situation well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, but you should contact Apple in your country to get a definitive answer.

Comment: I don't have a proper support program in my country , just email address who will get back to me after several days.

Comment: I'd say that's your best option, then. I have no idea how Apple's UTD program is set up, but it's safer to not go buying stuff when you're not certain you'll get a refund.

Comment: I bought it anyway, will update this answer afterwards if I get a refund

Comment: When you know if you're getting a refund, add your own answer and accept it. It may also be useful to mention what country you're in so future searchers have a better idea of what to expect. Good luck!

Comment: sure , I will do it.